# Control Worklight Direct Update using JNDI and Worklight Properties

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I'm using WL with server version : 6.2.0.01.20141013-1735

And I have the following security test:

```
<customSecurityTest name="AppTestMobile">
            <test realm="wl_antiXSRFRealm" step="2"/>
            <test realm="wl_authenticityRealm" step="2"/>
            <test realm="wl_remoteDisableRealm" step="2"/>
            <test realm="wl_directUpdateRealm" mode="perSession" step="1"/>
            <test realm="wl_anonymousUserRealm" isInternalUserID="true" step="2"/>
            <test realm="wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm" isInternalDeviceID="true" step="2"/>
</customSecurityTest>
```

I want to control the mode in the direct update using Worklight.Properties to avoid redeploying the WAR file every time I make a change on it.

Can I control a value in the security test using JNDI.

For example:

```
<test realm="wl_directUpdateRealm" mode="${DIRECT_UPDAT_MODE}" step="1"/>
```

and in Worklight.properties:

```
DIRECT_UPDAT_MODE = preSession
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK you cannot use variables in authenticationConfig.xml.

Additionally I do not see how this would help anyway? worklight.properties is part of the .war file... you will still need to re-deploy the .war file.

Comment: Thank you Idan, I just thought I can control it to avoid redeploying.